# Domain with cloudflare trough other domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, cloudflare

I have a domain with a provider that doesn't allow nameservers editing but i need it to be handled by cloudflare. I have another domain wich i dontuse. Is it a good idea to change the nameservers of the second domain to cloudflare and then point the first to the second with a cname record?

Comment: You can't have a CNAME as an apex record, so that'll cause you troubles. The real solution here is "ditch the shitty provider". Not being able to use your own nameservers is egregiously bad.

Comment: `I have a domain with a provider that doesn't allow nameservers editing` - Are you referring to the domain Registrar? - `i need it to be handled by cloudflare` - You need what to be handled by Cloudflare? Give us specifics.

Comment: There should be no such thing as a "provider" (registrar) that doesn't allow editing the authoritative nameservers.  These records are **not** the same thing as the `NS` records.  If you are trying to edit `NS` records, that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a domain with a provider that doesn't allow nameservers editing

Full stop. This is terrible. When you say "provider" are you talking about a registrar? Because I'm not even sure that's allowable under ICANN's rules. You need to change registrars.

> but i need it to be handled by cloudflare.

No, you need to move your domain to a new registrar, if indeed this is a registrar that you're discussing. =)

> I have another domain wich i dontuse. Is it a good idea to change the nameservers of the second domain to cloudflare and then point the first to the second with a cname record?

No, as @ceejayoz pointed out, CNAMEs are not supported as an apex record. What you ***could*** do (read: Don't do this, it's terrible), is abuse the heck out of your HTTP server's rewrite engine for Domain A to pull from Domain B which is being served by Cloudflare.

This is an awful idea, and will be an exercise in your ability to endure self hatred and loathing. Instead, go back to the first recommendation: You need to change registrars.